# mobile web - Opening native mapping application with anchor's href?

Tags: android, ios, html, geolocation, mobile-website

I've been developing an application for the Business for which I work, and thus far, I have succeeded in making each page mobile/desktop compliant using a combination of media queries and IE conditional comments, but the "locations" page has me stumped.
I want the address of each location to serve as a link which will be treated the way different MIME types are treated. Android seems to have this functionality covered with "intents" IE

```
geo:0,0?address
```

This also works on my N9, though from my testing using the iOS simulator, that can't open a "geo:" link. Is there a cross-browser way to create this functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, I've continued working on this issue, and both iOS and Android prompt the user to open the directions in the native application (hooray!) though my N9 does not view the google maps url as anything special, and Google doesn't see fit to include the UA in its fancy new web app maps.